# xml parsing problem using <![CDATA][

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

i'm having a strange problem with my xml (i'm parsing it with jQuery):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<root>
    <msg><![CDATA[<b>Email was sent!</b>]]</msg>     
    <cod>ok</cod>
</root>
```

when parsing - retrieving `<cod>` works but `<msg>` doesn't (it returns blank).
it works when omitting the `<![CDATA[` tag .. this is strange - i checked the syntax and it must be correct :/

any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CDATA` section must be closed with `]]>`, you are missing the `>`.

Answer (score 4):

Your CDATA block is not closed so you have invalid XML - A CDATA section starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>` so it should be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1' ?>
<root>
  <msg><![CDATA[<b>Email was sent!</b>]]></msg>     
    <cod>ok</cod>
</root>
```